# Pass the text from a form Select-Option to a text input field

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I would like to pass the text portion (not the value) of a form Select-Option to a hidden text-input field within the same form when the user makes a selection.

I have explored some java and PHP 'examples' I found in my research, but none of them seem to work for me.

I have posted a raw example of the form to see if anyone can lead me to water. Any help wouold be appreciated.

HMTL

```
<html>
<head>
</head>    
<body>

<form action="fruitBasket.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<select id="fruitSelector"  name="fruitSelector">

<option value="0" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Fruit</option>
<option value="1">Grapes</option>
<option value="2">Strawberries</option>
<option value="3">Peaches</option>
<option value="4">Blueberries</option>

</select>    

<br>
<br>

<input type="text" class="hiddenField" name="hiddenField" placeholder="Selected fruit appears 
here.">

</form>

</body>    

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as easy as getting the selected option's value, which can be retrieved simply as `selectElement.value`, yet it's not difficult at all.

`selectElement.options` will give you an array of ALL the options inside the select element.
You will find the selected option's index to be `selectElement.selectedIndex`.

With that said, you can access to the selected option like this: `selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex]`.

Finally, you can get the `text` property like this: `selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].text`

Here's the code:

```js
// THIS CONSTANT REPRESENTS THE <select> ELEMENT
const theSelect = document.getElementById('fruitSelector')

// THIS LINE BINDS THE input EVENT TO THE ABOVE select ELEMENT
// IT WILL BE EXECUTED EVERYTIME THE USER SELECTS AN OPTION
theSelect.addEventListener('input', function() {

  // THIS IS HOW YOU GET THE SELECTED OPTION'S TEXT
  let selectedOptText = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].text
  
  // FINALLY, THIS COPIES THE ABOVE TEXT TO THE INPUT ELEMENT:
  document.querySelector('.hiddenField').value = selectedOptText;

})
```

```html
<form action="fruitBasket.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <select id="fruitSelector" name="fruitSelector">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Fruit</option>
    <option value="1">Grapes</option>
    <option value="2">Strawberries</option>
    <option value="3">Peaches</option>
    <option value="4">Blueberries</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <br>

  <input type="text" class="hiddenField" name="hiddenField" placeholder="Selected fruit appears 
here.">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

well if you want to pass the text portion you should add the names as the values too like

```
---
code
---
<option value="Grapes">Grapes</option>
<option value="Strawberries">Strawberries</option>
---
code
---
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the description... I do not want to use the value. In the real form, the value will be used for something else.

Comment: It is never needed or beneficial to duplicate the option's text as its `value` attribute -- just omit the `value` declaration entirely.